# Java 8 stream: collecting a map to a map and constructors

Tags: java, java-8

I understand how you can process the entries of a map and collect the resulting stream into a different map. But I need to put the value using a constructor to which the previous map's key is passed and I can't figure out how to do it.

The scenario is the following:

I have a `Map<Event, EventSchedule> schedules`, and I want to get a `Map<Event, InverseSchedule>` from it. An `InverseSchedule` is constructed with an `Event`, precisely each key in `schedules`.

This is what I tried so far, and I am just one piece away from finally achieving what I'm after:

```
Map<Event, InverseSchedule> inverseSchedules = schedules.get()
        .keySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), ???));
```

I have tried `InverseSchedule::new` but of course that doesn't work because I am passing no arguments, and I couldn't do it using a lambda either.

I am still struggling to understand these new Java 8 features. I would really appreciate if the answer included the explanation of *why it works* rather than just providing the missing piece.

Comment: `InverseSchedule::new`, assuming there is a constructor of `InverseSchedule` taking an `Event`?

Comment: Why is `InverseSchedule::new` not working? Stream will pass argument to it, it will be an Event. It would be best if you could show us the mentioned constructor.

Comment: You should add information about your classes if you want an answer to that - those are not classes in the standard Java library, so we don't know what constructors or methods they offer. How do you make an `InverseSchedule` from an `Event`? Don't you want any information from the value (`EventSchedule`)? Please [edit] your question and expand.

Comment: `InverseSchedule::new` is not working. It says `cannot resolve constructor 'InverseSchedule'`. Maybe the fact that's overloaded is causing this problem? There are actually two constructors: `InverseSchedule(Event)` and `InverseSchedule(Tournament)`. Might this be the issue?

Comment: @RealSkeptic is it really relevant to the question how I make an `InverseSchedule` from an `Event`? Well, I don't want any information from the `EventSchedule` because that event schedule is actually grabbed through the event passed to the `InverseSchedule` constructor. Both kind of schedules are constructed from an `Event`.

Comment: Overloaded constructors are no problem. But the constructor must be accessible, i.e. either `public` or non-`private` within the same `package`. If in doubt, write the non-Stream equivalent solution first and check, whether there are any compiler errors…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would work. Also, `schedules.get()` is not required.

```
Map<Event, InverseSchedule> inverseSchedules = schedules
    .keySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), event -> new InverseSchedule(event));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use correct constructor in lambda expression

```
Map<Event, InverseSchedule> inverseSchedules = schedules.keySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), event -> new InverseSchedule(event));
```

Comment: If `event -> new InverseSchedule(event)` works, `InverseSchedule::new` should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

When building complex streams it is often hard to keep track of all the implicit generic parameters, so my usual approach, if I'm having trouble, is to temporarily break the stream build into individual statements, thus:

```
    Map<Event,EventSchedule> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    Set<Event> ks = map1.keySet();
    Stream<Event> st = ks.stream();
    Collector<Event,?,Map<Event,InverseSchedule>> coll = Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), e -> new InverseSchedule(e));
    Map<Event,InverseSchedule> map2 = st.collect(coll);
```

This makes it clear how the various steps are composed. Once you get it working this way you can combine them into a single statement.